# Invoke another web service after end of BPEL process

Tags: oracle, web-services, oracle11g, soa, bpel

I have the following structure in my BPEL process.

```
-> Start process
Invoke web service ->
Do something
Invoke another web service ->
<- Send answer
```

This synchronous BPEL 2.0 process is implemented in a service I created with Oracle SOA Suite 11g. I want to alter the process to the following:

```
-> Start process
Invoke web service ->
<- Send answer
Do something
Invoke another web service ->
```

My problem is that the instance that calls my web service and therefor triggers this BPEL process only needs to know the result of the web service invoked first, the parts "Do something" and the invocation of the other web service can take several seconds and from time to time cause a time out on the consumer side. So the BPEL process has to send the answer after the first invoke but still has do to other stuff. I tried just putting the reply of the output right after the first invocation, but the web service still seems to wait for it to completely finish before continuing in sending the answer to the consumer. Probably because it's defined as a synchronous web service. But I guess I can't define it as an asynchronous service, because the answer of the first invoke is needed. Or do I have to create a second BPEL process which contains just the two last parts and make this one asynchronous? But keep in mind that in the "Do something" part I also need the answer from the first invocation.

Sorry for any errors, I'm not a native English speaker. And thanks for any help!

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds odd. The reply shouldn't have to wait for the "Do something" part. If it does, then this sounds like a bug. If the "do something" / second invoke and the reply are unrelated, then maybe executing them in parallel (flow activity) might help?

Comment: Yeah, I know did a similar thing: I just added another BPEL process. The mediator in the composite now starts both BPEL processes.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just added another BPEL process. Now I have a synchronous and an asynchronous process, both started at the mediator in the composite. Probably not the perfect solution but it does the trick for me.